# Display a Word Document

Tags: 2010, word

Is there a way to display a `word document` in a web part like you can display a `Excel spreadsheet` using the `Excel Webpart`?

Comment: what is your sharepoint version?

Answer (score 1):

You can put `Iframe` on your web part and assign document `url` to `iframe url`,
or you can setup office app web server and you can display word as noraml on the browser 
by using this event when use click on the document

```
onclick="return DispEx(this,event,'TRUE','FALSE','FALSE','SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3','1','SharePoint.OpenDocuments','','','','1073741823','1','0','0x7fffffffffffffff')"
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to Save the word document as an HTML file.

Then upload the file into a document library. Then use Page Viewer Webpart to display it.